# Asks for input but doesn't acknowledge

Tags: python, input

**When you Run the program and  select something it sometimes doesn't acknowledge the input. Sorry if there is a obvious mistake. I am still quite new at this. Thanks for all the help in advance.**
This is not a major problem but it is for a school thing so preferably I would like to fix it.

```
import webbrowser as web
import random as rand
print('1: Website Listings')
print('2: Password Generator')
print('3: Number Guessing Game')
print('4: Calculator')
while True:
    user_input1 = str(input(': '))
    print('')

#Website Listings:

    if user_input1 == '1':  
        print('1: Google')
        print('2: Youtube')
        print('3: 9GAG')
        print('4: CanYouRunIt')

        user_input2 = str(input(': '))

        if user_input2 == '1':
            web.open('https://www.google.co.za/')
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        if user_input2 == '2':
            web.open('https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ZA')
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        if user_input2 == '3':
            web.open('http://9gag.com/')
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))


        if user_input2 == '4':
            web.open('http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri')
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

#Password Generator:

    if user_input1 == '2':
        total_digits = 0
        max_digits = int(input('How many digits? '))
        while total_digits != max_digits:
            print(rand.randint(0,9))
            total_digits+=1
        print('')
        print('1: Website Listings')
        print('2: Password Generator')
        print('3: Number Guessing Game')
        print('4: Calculator')
        user_input1 = str(input(': '))

#Number Guessing Game:
    if user_input1 == '3':
        print('')
        lower_value = int(input('Lowest Number: '))
        print(' ')
        higher_value = int(input('Highest Number: '))
        print(' ')
        tries = int(input('Amount of tries before failure: '))
        print(' ')
        answer = rand.randint(lower_value, higher_value)

        while tries != 0:
            guess = int(input('Your guess: '))
            if guess > answer:
                print('The answer is smaller')
                tries-=1
                print('You have ' + str(tries) + ' try(ies)' + ' left')
                print(' ')
            elif guess < answer:
                print('The answer is larger')
                tries-=1
                print('You have ' + str(tries) + ' try3(ies)' + ' left')
                print(' ')
            elif guess == answer:
                print('!!! YOU WON !!!')
                print('You had ' + str(tries) + ' try(ies)' + ' left')
                print(' ')
                break
            if tries == 0:
                print('!!! YOU LOSE !!!')
                print(' ')
                break
        print('')
        print('1: Website Listings')
        print('2: Password Generator')
        print('3: Number Guessing Game')
        print('4: Calculator')
        user_input1 = str(input(': '))

#Calculator:

    print('')    
    if user_input1 == '4':
        print('These are your options: ')
        print('Type "1" to add two numbers')
        print('Type "2" to subtract two numbers')
        print('Type "3" to multiply two numbers')
        print('Type "4" to divide two numbers')
        print('Type "5" to determine the product of an exponent')
        print('Type "6" to return to main screen')
        print('')

        user_input3 = input('What do you want to do? ')

        if user_input3 == '6':
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        elif user_input3 == '1':
            num1 = float(input('Please enter the first number: '))
            num2 = float(input('Please enter a second number to add: '))
            result=str(num1 + num2)
            print('The answer is: ' + result)
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        elif user_input3 == '2':
            num1 = float(input('Please enter the first number: '))
            num2 = float(input('Please enter a second number to subtract: '))
            result=str(num1 - num2)
            print('The answer is: ' + result)
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        elif user_input3 == '3':
            num1 = float(input('Please enter the first number: '))
            num2 = float(input(' Please enter a second number to multiply: '))
            result = str(num1 * num2)
            print('The answer is: ' + result)
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        elif user_input3 == '4':
            num1 = float(input('Please enter the first number '))
            num2 = float(input('Please enter a second number to divide by: '))
            result = str(num1 / num2)
            print('The answer is: ' + result)
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        elif user_input3 == '5':
            num1 = float(input('Please enter the base number: '))
            num2 = float(input('Please enter the exponent: '))
            result = str(num1 ** num2)
            print('The answer is: ' + result)
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))

        else:
            print('Unknown command')
            print('')
            print('1: Website Listings')
            print('2: Password Generator')
            print('3: Number Guessing Game')
            print('4: Calculator')
            user_input1 = str(input(': '))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`input` returns a string already, so there is no point in casting it to a string again using `str`. Since your input will be a number, convert it to an integer instead

```
# ... rest of your code

inp = input("Enter a numerical option: ")
try:
    inp = int(inp)
except:
    print(inp, "is not a valid option")
    continue   # this will skip everything below and go to the next instance of the while loop which will ask the user again for input

# ... rest of your code
```

---

In regards to the structure of the code, it can be split up into smaller functions that can be called instead.

```
def webListings():
    print('1: Google')
    ...

def passGen()
    print(...)
    ...
```

And then you can do something like this

```
if user_input1 == 1:
    webListings()
else if user_input1 == 2:
    passGen()
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end of all the first if statements, add a pass.